# Floating native view in MobileFirst

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins, mobilefirst-studio

I want to put an Android native videoview on top of my mobilefirst hybrid page

I have look into this link below and that dont help for putting a native view above the hybrid html page. (there are samples for creating native activity but thats not the case here)

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/adding-native-functionality/

I have Found a workaround and its working,But I want a proper solution for this

```html
public void onInitWebFrameworkComplete(WLInitWebFrameworkResult result){
  if (result.getStatusCode() == WLInitWebFrameworkResult.SUCCESS) {
   super.loadUrl(WL.getInstance().getMainHtmlFilePath());
   
   video1 = new VideoView(this);

   
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(300,300); //The WRAP_CONTENT parameters can be replaced by an absolute width and height or the FILL_PARENT option)
   params.leftMargin = 100; //Your X coordinate
   params.topMargin = 100; //Your Y coordinate
   
   super.addContentView(video1, params);
   
   video1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   
   
  } else {
   handleWebFrameworkInitFailure(result);
  }
 }

 private void handleWebFrameworkInitFailure(WLInitWebFrameworkResult result){
  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(R.string.close, new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
    finish();
   }
  });

  alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.error);
  alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(result.getMessage());
  alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).create().show();
 }
 
 @Override
 public void onActionReceived(String action, JSONObject data) {
   Log.d("TEST","********AM NATIVE**********");
   if (action.equals("start_video"))
  {
   Log.d("TEST","********starting Video**********");
     
   
   getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    
       public void run() 
       {

        video1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);       
        Uri uri=Uri.parse("/sdcard/a.mp4");        
           video1.setVideoURI(uri);   
           video1.start();
           Log.d("TEST","Inside Thread");
                   
           
       }
       
    });

    
  } else if (action.equals("stop_video")){
   
   Log.d("TEST","********Stop Video**********");
   video1.stopPlayback();
   video1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     
  }
   
 }
```

Comment: What makes you think this is a workaround and not a proper solution? This is not something the mobilefirst *should* give to you; if you get it working, then that is fine. You have the solution.

Comment: I want to know whether there is a feature like WL.NativePage.show or something for displaying just a view.

Comment: You can review the SendAction API in the MobileFirst Platform Knowledge Center.

Answer (score -1):

What makes you think this is a workaround and not a proper solution? This is not something the mobilefirst should give to you; if you get it working, then that is fine. You have the solution.

That said, you should look at these tutorials none the less:

- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/advanced-topics/integrating-server-generated-pages-hybrid-applications/
- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/adding-native-functionality/android-adding-native-ui-elements-hybrid-applications/

Comment: In my code am creating view at onInitWebFrameworkComplete() and make it hide using video1.setVisibility(View.GONE);   then display the native view whenever its needed (call from js to native).So the view is loaded at the application startup itself.so it may affect the app performance.